# importing class from icloud in python

Tags: python-import, icloud

I downloaded a python program which includes class from the WWW. I have stored it on "iCloud/Document/Work/Code Library/program.py". It contains Class1 that I want to import.

I have it stored on icloud and this is a condition that I can't change.

I am creating a ipynb which is also on icloud. How do I import the library from the program I downloaded.

How do I import? Thank you.

Comment: Wow, this looks like a cool idea. Try pyicloud: https://pypi.org/project/pyicloud/

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this using PyiCloud:

```
from pyicloud import PyiCloudService

# connect to the API
username = 'yourusername@apple.com'
password = 'password123'
api = PyiCloudService(username, password)

files = api.files.dir()

# you can figure out the file path
file_name = 'pythonfile.py'
download = api.files['com~apple~Notes']['Documents'][file_name].open(stream=True)
```

I assume that after that you can just import it right after, but if you can't, you can always just copy it onto your local device as a file and then import it:

```
import pythonfile
```

After that you can just delete it if you want.